# shared preference's key's value is being changed only once

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-theme

I'm trying to add a functionality of changing themes in my app. Showing an AlertDialog with single choice items (radio buttons) after a button gets clicked.

Here's the AlertDialog:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class ThemeDialog extends DialogFragment {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    int radioButton;
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.apply();

    if (preferences.getBoolean("has_theme_changed", false)) {
        radioButton = 1;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else { radioButton = 0; Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.theme_dialog_title)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.choose_a_theme, radioButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            editor.putBoolean("has_theme_changed", false);
                            editor.apply();
                            dismiss();
                        case 1:
                            editor.putBoolean("has_theme_changed", true);
                            editor.apply();
                            dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

First, what I want is when the user checks either of the radio button, next time it should be checked by default.

Second, according to the boolean value saved in the SharedPreference object, the theme should get changed in the MainActivity.

PROBLEM: The default value is 'false', so the theme is 'light' and 'Light Theme' radio button is checked. When I try to change it to 'Dark', it's working like a charm but it stops working afterwards. Can anyone point out what's wrong? And Please share your views if you think, there's a better way of changing app's theme at runtime. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have'nt specified any `KEY_NAME` in `preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);`

Comment: Try replacing `preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);` with `preferences = getActivity().getPreferences("SOME_KEYNAME",0);`

Comment: Why would I provide a key there? You need to provide MODE there.

Comment: @Lal No you don't need a name:
"getPreferences() — Use this from an Activity if you need to use only one shared preference file for the activity. Because this retrieves a default shared preference file that belongs to the activity, you don't need to supply a name." (src: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: I Agree! That's what I was talking about.

Comment: I guess every mistake makes you learn something.

Comment: But maybe you should use the constant (Context.MODE_PRIVATE) instead of "0" as it's gonna be easier for you or another dev to read the code later. :)

Comment: Got it! See my last comment now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you forgot to break your switch case.

```
switch (which) {
    case 0:
        editor.putBoolean("has_theme_changed", false);
        editor.apply();
        dismiss();
        break;
    case 1:
        editor.putBoolean("has_theme_changed", true);
        editor.apply();
        dismiss();
        break;
}
```

Btw you don't need the editor.apply() here:

```
preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
editor = preferences.edit();
//editor.apply();
```

Comment: you are making sense. Thanks! I'll try it tomorrow cause I shut down my system bro. Then I'll upvote it

Comment: I know I don't have to. But it was android studio made the code's last line yellow `preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
editor = preferences.edit(); ` and saying you have to call apply or commit to save changes. Can you enlighten me on this?

Comment: Basically AS expects you to apply or commit your changes when you create an editor. As you potentially don't change something (there is no 'default' in your switch) AS complains as it thinks you forgot to apply the changes in some cases.
I'd suggest to create the editor only when necessary. Example: case 0: preferences.edit().putBoolean("has_theme_changed", false).apply(); ....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

`preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(0);`

for this

`preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

And remember to set the string `preference_file_key` at strings.xml

Comment: Fonseca it's the same thing. Just a short form.

Answer (score 0):

I see something way simpler, remove that awful switch and just put the following inside your onClick():

```
editor.putBoolean("has_theme_changed", which == 1).apply();
dismiss();
```

There is no need for a switch nor to call dismiss() 2 times

I'm wondering if you even could do that in this case:

```
editor.putBoolean("has_theme_changed", Boolean.valueOf(which)).apply();
dismiss();
```

**Edit **

The second example doesn't seem to be correct, since the doc says that Boolean.valueOf only takes string or boolean value

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You can simplify even more:
editor.putBoolean("has_theme_changed", which == 1).apply();
dismiss();
Btw I'd suggest to use a constant instead of string for the key as you can make spelling mistakes next time you try to retrieve or update the data:
final static String KEY_HAS_THEME_CHANGED = "has_theme_changed";
And then:
editor.putBoolean(KEY_HAS_THEME_CHANGED, which == 1).apply();